# Why do I get empty array in ngOnInit after calling a method?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
getHistory(gaaNum): void {

this.loading = true;
this.gaaHistoryService.getHistory(gaaNum)
  .subscribe(atmHistory => {
    // I am more sure that real data gets assigned here!!!
    this.allChartData = atmHistory; // allChartData has a size of 152
    this.loading = false;
  }, err => {
    this.loading = false;
    this.errorMsg = err;
    console.log(`error: ${err}`);
  });
}
```

and yet, the allChartData public variable is empty here:

```
    ngOnInit() { 
    this.allChartData = [];
    this.amount= [];
    this.fillSum = [];
    this.barChartData = [];

    this.getHistory(this.gaaNumber);

    console.log(this.allChartData.length);  // this is zero, allChartdata is empty here. Why?



  }
```

How can I get the data outside of scope of 'subscribe'?

Comment: this.gaaHistoryService.getHistory is asynchronous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is asynchronous, so when you write

```
this.getHistory(this.gaaNumber);
console.log(this.allChartData.length);
```

`getHistory()` is called - and before it has time to finish, you are already calling `console.log(this.allChartData.length)` which will consequently print out 0.

If you instead write something like

```
  ...
  this.gaaHistoryService.getHistory(gaaNum)
  .subscribe(atmHistory => {
    // I am more sure that real data gets assigned here!!!
    this.allChartData = atmHistory; // allChartData has a size of 152
    console.log(this.allChartData.length);
    this.loading = false;
  },
  ...
```

you will get the number you're looking for.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right if I change this I get the correct numbers. Is there no way to get them in ngOnInit?

Comment: instead of calling subscribe inside your `getHistory(gaaNum)`, you could use `pipe` with `map` and `catchError` and return the resulting observable. Then you can use subscribe inside your `ngOnInit`

Comment: I created an answer to further explain what I mean

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to log it in your `ngOnInit`, you'll have to make your `getHistory` method into an observable. You can do this by piping into a `map` and `catchError` instead of subscribing, and return the result as follows:

```
getHistory(gaaNum): void {

    this.loading = true;
    return this.gaaHistoryService.getHistory(gaaNum)
      .pipe(map(atmHistory => {
        this.allChartData = atmHistory; 
        this.loading = false;
      }), catchError(err => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.errorMsg = err;
        console.log(`error: ${err}`);
      }));
}
```

Now, in your `ngOnInit`, you can subscribe to `getHistory` and do whatever you want.

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.allChartData = [];
    this.amount= [];
    this.fillSum = [];
    this.barChartData = [];

    this.getHistory(this.gaaNumber).subscribe(_ => { 
        console.log(this.allChartData.length);
    });
}
```

Comment: Also a great answer